# How do I access the properties of objects that are placed a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that sends a json string of objects to my javascript file.  I am having problems accessing the properties of objects that are contained within this javascript object.

My php file:

```
 for($i=0; $i<$hitcount; $i++){
        if($i == $hitcount-1){
            // IF HITCOUNT IS LESS THAN 25 RESULTS
            echo json_encode($articleArray);
            exit();
        }else if($i == 25){
            // THERE IS ONLY A MAX OF 25 RESULTS PER REQUEST
            echo json_encode($articleArray);
            exit();
        }else{
            $page = $xml -> request  -> page ; //always page 1

    $title = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> title;
        if($title == false){
            $title = '';
        }

    $pmid = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> pmid;
        if($pmid == false){
            $pmid = '';
        }

    $authorString = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> authorString;
        if($authorString == false){
            $authorString ='';
        }
    $journalTitle  = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> journalTitle ;
        if($journalTitle ==false){
            $journalTitle = '';
        }
    $pubYear = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> pubYear;
        if($pubYear == false){
            $pubYear = '';
        }
    $journalVolume = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> journalVolume;
        if($journalVolume == false){
            $journalVolume = '';
        }
    $issue = $xml ->resultList -> result[v] -> issue;
        if($issue == false){
            $issue = '';
        }
    $pageInfo = $xml ->resultList -> result[$i] -> pageInfo;
        if($pageInfo == false){
            $pageInfo = '';
        }


        $articleArray[] = array(
            'hitCount' => $hitcount,
            'page' => $page,
            'pmid' => $pmid,
            'title' => $title,
            'authors' => $authorString,
            'journalTitle' => $journalTitle,
            'pubYear' => $pubYear,
            'journalVolume' => $journalVolume,
            'issue' => $issue,
            'pageInfo' => $pageInfo
            );
        }
    }
```

my javascript file:

```
 // Retrieve json string
var json_obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I have tried the following to access the properties of the objects that are stored in the javascript object:

```
 json_obj[0].title // to access the title of the first object
```

This just returns:

```
 [object Object]
```

xmlhttp.responseText:

```
 [{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25745995"},"title":{"0":"Hypoxia upregulates Rab11-family interacting protein 4 through HIF-1\u03b1 to promote the metastasis of hepatocellular carcinoma."},"authors":{"0":"Hu F, Deng X, Yang X, Jin H, Gu D, Lv X, Wang C, Zhang Y, Huo X, Shen Q, Luo Q, Zhao F, Ge T, Zhao F, Chu W, Shu H, Yao M, Fan J, Qin W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Oncogene"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800835"},"title":{"0":"Kinetic activation of Rab8 guanine nucleotide exchange factor Rabin8 by Rab11."},"authors":{"0":"Feng S, Wu B, Per\u00e4nen J, Guo W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"99-106"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26032412"},"title":{"0":"Structure-Function Analyses of the Interactions Between Rab11 and Rab14 Small GTPases with their Shared Effector Rab Coupling Protein (RCP)."},"authors":{"0":"Lall P, Lindsay A, Hanscom S, Kecman T, Taglauer ES, McVeigh UM, Franklin E, McCaffrey MW, Khan AR."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Biol Chem"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25815277"},"title":{"0":"Rab11 in disease progression."},"authors":{"0":"Bhuin T, Roy JK."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Int J Mol Cell Med"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"4"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1-8"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800843"},"title":{"0":"In vitro and in vivo characterization of the Rab11-GAP activity of Drosophila Evi5."},"authors":{"0":"Laflamme C, Emery G."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"187-194"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"24917558"},"title":{"0":"Vasodilator-stimulated phosphoprotein promotes activation of hepatic stellate cells by regulating Rab11-dependent plasma membrane targeting of transforming growth factor beta receptors."},"authors":{"0":"Tu K, Li J, Verma VK, Liu C, Billadeau DD, Lamprecht G, Xiang X, Guo L, Dhanasekaran R, Roberts LR, Shah VH, Kang N."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Hepatology"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"61"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"361-374"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25480917"},"title":{"0":"Vangl2 cooperates with Rab11 and Myosin V to regulate apical constriction during vertebrate gastrulation."},"authors":{"0":"Ossipova O, Chuykin I, Chu CW, Sokol SY."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Development"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"142"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"99-107"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25831508"},"title":{"0":"TRAPPII regulates exocytic Golgi exit by mediating nucleotide exchange on the Ypt31 ortholog RabERAB11."},"authors":{"0":"Pinar M, Arst HN Jr, Pantazopoulou A, Tagua VG, de los R\u00edos V, Rodr\u00edguez-Salarichs J, D\u00edaz JF, Pe\u00f1alva MA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"112"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"4346-4351"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25305083"},"title":{"0":"Rab11 modulates \u03b1-synuclein-mediated defects in synaptic transmission and behaviour."},"authors":{"0":"Breda C, Nugent ML, Estranero JG, Kyriacou CP, Outeiro TF, Steinert JR, Giorgini F."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Hum Mol Genet"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"24"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1077-1091"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25862161"},"title":{"0":"A novel role of Rab11 in trafficking GPI-anchored trans-sialidase to the plasma membrane of Trypanosoma cruzi."},"authors":{"0":"Niyogi S, Docampo R."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Small GTPases"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"6"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"8-10"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25673879"},"title":{"0":"The Arf and Rab11 effector FIP3 acts synergistically with ASAP1 to direct Rabin8 in ciliary receptor targeting."},"authors":{"0":"Wang J, Deretic D."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Sci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"128"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1375-1385"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25972173"},"title":{"0":"Synaptic Function of Rab11Fip5: Selective Requirement for Hippocampal Long-Term Depression."},"authors":{"0":"Bacaj T, Ahmad M, Jurado S, Malenka RC, S\u00fcdhof TC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Neurosci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"35"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"7460-7474"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25632160"},"title":{"0":"Myosin Va mediates BDNF-induced postendocytic recycling of full-length TrkB and its translocation into dendritic spines."},"authors":{"0":"Sui WH, Huang SH, Wang J, Chen Q, Liu T, Chen ZY."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Sci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"128"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1108-1122"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25686250"},"title":{"0":"Early steps in primary cilium assembly require EHD1\/EHD3-dependent ciliary vesicle formation."},"authors":{"0":"Lu Q, Insinna C, Ott C, Stauffer J, Pintado PA, Rahajeng J, Baxa U, Walia V, Cuenca A, Hwang YS, Daar IO, Lopes S, Lippincott-Schwartz J, Jackson PK, Caplan S, Westlake CJ."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Nat Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"17"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"228-240"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25904794"},"title":{"0":"Protein Interacting with C-Kinase 1 Deficiency Impairs Glutathione Synthesis and Increases Oxidative Stress via Reduction of Surface Excitatory Amino Acid Carrier 1."},"authors":{"0":"Wang YN, Zhou L, Li YH, Wang Z, Li YC, Zhang YW, Wang Y, Liu G, Shen Y."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Neurosci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"35"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"6429-6443"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26041286"},"title":{"0":"Intracellular Transport of Vaccinia Virus in HeLa Cells Requires WASH-VPEF\/FAM21-Retromer Complexes and Recycling molecules Rab11 and Rab22."},"authors":{"0":"Hsiao JC, Chu LW, Lo YT, Lee SP, Chen TJ, Huang CY, Ping YH, Chang W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Virol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25704914"},"title":{"0":"Mechanisms regulating cell membrane localization of the chemokine receptor CXCR4 in human hepatocarcinoma cells."},"authors":{"0":"Cepeda EB, Dediulia T, Fernando J, Bertran E, Egea G, Navarro E, Fabregat I."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Biochim Biophys Acta"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1853"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1205-1218"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26021297"},"title":{"0":"The small GTPase Rab29 is a common regulator of immune synapse assembly and ciliogenesis."},"authors":{"0":"Onnis A, Finetti F, Patrussi L, Gottardo M, Cassioli C, Span\u00f2 S, Baldari CT."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Cell Death Differ"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26004511"},"title":{"0":"Slitrk5 Mediates BDNF-Dependent TrkB Receptor Trafficking and Signaling."},"authors":{"0":"Song M, Giza J, Proenca CC, Jing D, Elliott M, Dincheva I, Shmelkov SV, Kim J, Schreiner R, Huang SH, Castr\u00e9n E, Prekeris R, Hempstead BL, Chao MV, Dictenberg JB, Rafii S, Chen ZY, Rodriguez-Boulan E, Lee FS."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Dev Cell"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"33"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"690-702"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25753037"},"title":{"0":"LTP-triggered cholesterol redistribution activates Cdc42 and drives AMPA receptor synaptic delivery."},"authors":{"0":"Brachet A, Norwood S, Brouwers JF, Palomer E, Helms JB, Dotti CG, Esteban JA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"208"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"791-806"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26110570"},"title":{"0":"Predominant Rab-GTPase amplicons contributing to oral squamous cell carcinoma progression to metastasis."},"authors":{"0":"da Silva SD, Marchi FA, Xu B, Bijian K, Alobaid F, Mlynarek A, Rogatto SR, Hier M, Kowalski LP, Alaoui-Jamali MA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Oncotarget"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26067165"},"title":{"0":"Site-Specific Phosphorylation of VEGFR2 Is Mediated by Receptor Trafficking: Insights from a Computational Model."},"authors":{"0":"Clegg LW, Mac Gabhann F."},"journalTitle":{"0":"PLoS Comput Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"11"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"e1004158"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25941134"},"title":{"0":"Mechanisms of apical-basal axis orientation and epithelial lumen positioning."},"authors":{"0":"Overeem AW, Bryant DM, van IJzendoorn SC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Trends Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25394938"},"title":{"0":"The fungal pathogen Cryptococcus neoformans manipulates macrophage phagosome maturation."},"authors":{"0":"Smith LM, Dixon EF, May RC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Cell Microbiol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"17"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"702-713"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800842"},"title":{"0":"3D time-lapse analysis of Rab11\/FIP5 complex: spatiotemporal dynamics during apical lumen formation."},"authors":{"0":"Mangan A, Prekeris R."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"181-186"}}]
```

Comment: Can you describe the output here?

Comment: What does the json string `json_obj` look like in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the title is really an `Object`.

```
"title":{
    "0":"Hypoxia upregulates Rab11-family interacting protein 4 through HIF-1\u03b1 to promote the metastasis of hepatocellular carcinoma."
}
```

If you can't change the output try to access like this:

```
json_obj[0].title["0"];
```

But would be better if the title comes from your php ready to use. I don't see any reason to return an array in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the title to a string value:

```
$title = (string) $xml->resultList->result[$i]->title;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your XML/JSON conversion in PHP. I'm not sure of your XML structure, but you're currently passing an object instead of a value. Building on @Stefan's answer above, it might be worth simplifying the process with a function:

```
// get the title, etc...    
$title = attr_val( $xml->resultList->result[$i]->title );

function attr_val ( $attr ) {
  return (string) ($attr ?: "");
}
```

You can solve this on the front end as well:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(responseText);

// iterate over each reference
for(i in data) {
  
  // and it's attributes
  for(attr in data[i]) {
    
    // look for objects where you were expecting strings
    if(data[i][attr].hasOwnProperty("0")) {
      
      // replace with the string you were expecting
      data[i][attr] = data[i][attr]["0"];
    }
  }
}

// You can now access all attributes as expected
data[0].title

// See the full output
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre></pre><script>var responseText = '[{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25745995"},"title":{"0":"Hypoxia upregulates Rab11-family interacting protein 4 through HIF-1\u03b1 to promote the metastasis of hepatocellular carcinoma."},"authors":{"0":"Hu F, Deng X, Yang X, Jin H, Gu D, Lv X, Wang C, Zhang Y, Huo X, Shen Q, Luo Q, Zhao F, Ge T, Zhao F, Chu W, Shu H, Yao M, Fan J, Qin W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Oncogene"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800835"},"title":{"0":"Kinetic activation of Rab8 guanine nucleotide exchange factor Rabin8 by Rab11."},"authors":{"0":"Feng S, Wu B, Per\u00e4nen J, Guo W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"99-106"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26032412"},"title":{"0":"Structure-Function Analyses of the Interactions Between Rab11 and Rab14 Small GTPases with their Shared Effector Rab Coupling Protein (RCP)."},"authors":{"0":"Lall P, Lindsay A, Hanscom S, Kecman T, Taglauer ES, McVeigh UM, Franklin E, McCaffrey MW, Khan AR."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Biol Chem"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25815277"},"title":{"0":"Rab11 in disease progression."},"authors":{"0":"Bhuin T, Roy JK."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Int J Mol Cell Med"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"4"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1-8"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800843"},"title":{"0":"In vitro and in vivo characterization of the Rab11-GAP activity of Drosophila Evi5."},"authors":{"0":"Laflamme C, Emery G."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"187-194"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"24917558"},"title":{"0":"Vasodilator-stimulated phosphoprotein promotes activation of hepatic stellate cells by regulating Rab11-dependent plasma membrane targeting of transforming growth factor beta receptors."},"authors":{"0":"Tu K, Li J, Verma VK, Liu C, Billadeau DD, Lamprecht G, Xiang X, Guo L, Dhanasekaran R, Roberts LR, Shah VH, Kang N."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Hepatology"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"61"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"361-374"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25480917"},"title":{"0":"Vangl2 cooperates with Rab11 and Myosin V to regulate apical constriction during vertebrate gastrulation."},"authors":{"0":"Ossipova O, Chuykin I, Chu CW, Sokol SY."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Development"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"142"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"99-107"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25831508"},"title":{"0":"TRAPPII regulates exocytic Golgi exit by mediating nucleotide exchange on the Ypt31 ortholog RabERAB11."},"authors":{"0":"Pinar M, Arst HN Jr, Pantazopoulou A, Tagua VG, de los R\u00edos V, Rodr\u00edguez-Salarichs J, D\u00edaz JF, Pe\u00f1alva MA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"112"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"4346-4351"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25305083"},"title":{"0":"Rab11 modulates \u03b1-synuclein-mediated defects in synaptic transmission and behaviour."},"authors":{"0":"Breda C, Nugent ML, Estranero JG, Kyriacou CP, Outeiro TF, Steinert JR, Giorgini F."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Hum Mol Genet"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"24"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1077-1091"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25862161"},"title":{"0":"A novel role of Rab11 in trafficking GPI-anchored trans-sialidase to the plasma membrane of Trypanosoma cruzi."},"authors":{"0":"Niyogi S, Docampo R."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Small GTPases"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"6"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"8-10"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25673879"},"title":{"0":"The Arf and Rab11 effector FIP3 acts synergistically with ASAP1 to direct Rabin8 in ciliary receptor targeting."},"authors":{"0":"Wang J, Deretic D."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Sci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"128"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1375-1385"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25972173"},"title":{"0":"Synaptic Function of Rab11Fip5: Selective Requirement for Hippocampal Long-Term Depression."},"authors":{"0":"Bacaj T, Ahmad M, Jurado S, Malenka RC, S\u00fcdhof TC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Neurosci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"35"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"7460-7474"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25632160"},"title":{"0":"Myosin Va mediates BDNF-induced postendocytic recycling of full-length TrkB and its translocation into dendritic spines."},"authors":{"0":"Sui WH, Huang SH, Wang J, Chen Q, Liu T, Chen ZY."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Sci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"128"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1108-1122"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25686250"},"title":{"0":"Early steps in primary cilium assembly require EHD1\/EHD3-dependent ciliary vesicle formation."},"authors":{"0":"Lu Q, Insinna C, Ott C, Stauffer J, Pintado PA, Rahajeng J, Baxa U, Walia V, Cuenca A, Hwang YS, Daar IO, Lopes S, Lippincott-Schwartz J, Jackson PK, Caplan S, Westlake CJ."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Nat Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"17"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"228-240"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25904794"},"title":{"0":"Protein Interacting with C-Kinase 1 Deficiency Impairs Glutathione Synthesis and Increases Oxidative Stress via Reduction of Surface Excitatory Amino Acid Carrier 1."},"authors":{"0":"Wang YN, Zhou L, Li YH, Wang Z, Li YC, Zhang YW, Wang Y, Liu G, Shen Y."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Neurosci"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"35"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"6429-6443"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26041286"},"title":{"0":"Intracellular Transport of Vaccinia Virus in HeLa Cells Requires WASH-VPEF\/FAM21-Retromer Complexes and Recycling molecules Rab11 and Rab22."},"authors":{"0":"Hsiao JC, Chu LW, Lo YT, Lee SP, Chen TJ, Huang CY, Ping YH, Chang W."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Virol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25704914"},"title":{"0":"Mechanisms regulating cell membrane localization of the chemokine receptor CXCR4 in human hepatocarcinoma cells."},"authors":{"0":"Cepeda EB, Dediulia T, Fernando J, Bertran E, Egea G, Navarro E, Fabregat I."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Biochim Biophys Acta"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1853"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"1205-1218"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26021297"},"title":{"0":"The small GTPase Rab29 is a common regulator of immune synapse assembly and ciliogenesis."},"authors":{"0":"Onnis A, Finetti F, Patrussi L, Gottardo M, Cassioli C, Span\u00f2 S, Baldari CT."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Cell Death Differ"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26004511"},"title":{"0":"Slitrk5 Mediates BDNF-Dependent TrkB Receptor Trafficking and Signaling."},"authors":{"0":"Song M, Giza J, Proenca CC, Jing D, Elliott M, Dincheva I, Shmelkov SV, Kim J, Schreiner R, Huang SH, Castr\u00e9n E, Prekeris R, Hempstead BL, Chao MV, Dictenberg JB, Rafii S, Chen ZY, Rodriguez-Boulan E, Lee FS."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Dev Cell"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"33"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"690-702"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25753037"},"title":{"0":"LTP-triggered cholesterol redistribution activates Cdc42 and drives AMPA receptor synaptic delivery."},"authors":{"0":"Brachet A, Norwood S, Brouwers JF, Palomer E, Helms JB, Dotti CG, Esteban JA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"J Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"208"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"791-806"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26110570"},"title":{"0":"Predominant Rab-GTPase amplicons contributing to oral squamous cell carcinoma progression to metastasis."},"authors":{"0":"da Silva SD, Marchi FA, Xu B, Bijian K, Alobaid F, Mlynarek A, Rogatto SR, Hier M, Kowalski LP, Alaoui-Jamali MA."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Oncotarget"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"26067165"},"title":{"0":"Site-Specific Phosphorylation of VEGFR2 Is Mediated by Receptor Trafficking: Insights from a Computational Model."},"authors":{"0":"Clegg LW, Mac Gabhann F."},"journalTitle":{"0":"PLoS Comput Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"11"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"e1004158"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25941134"},"title":{"0":"Mechanisms of apical-basal axis orientation and epithelial lumen positioning."},"authors":{"0":"Overeem AW, Bryant DM, van IJzendoorn SC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Trends Cell Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":"","issue":"","pageInfo":""},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25394938"},"title":{"0":"The fungal pathogen Cryptococcus neoformans manipulates macrophage phagosome maturation."},"authors":{"0":"Smith LM, Dixon EF, May RC."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Cell Microbiol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"17"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"702-713"}},{"hitCount":{"0":"3347"},"page":{"0":"1"},"pmid":{"0":"25800842"},"title":{"0":"3D time-lapse analysis of Rab11\/FIP5 complex: spatiotemporal dynamics during apical lumen formation."},"authors":{"0":"Mangan A, Prekeris R."},"journalTitle":{"0":"Methods Mol Biol"},"pubYear":{"0":"2015"},"journalVolume":{"0":"1298"},"issue":"","pageInfo":{"0":"181-186"}}]';</script>
```